# puppet file function doesn't load contents

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, puppet

I am trying to use the puppet file function (not the type) in the following way

```
class iop_users {

include 's3file::curl'
include 'stdlib'

$secretpath=file('/etc/secret','dev/null')

notify { 'show secretpath':
  message =>"secretpath is $secretpath"
}

s3file { '/opt/utab.yaml':
  source => "mybucket/$secretpath/utab.yaml",
  ensure => 'latest',
}

exec { 'fix perms':
  command => '/bin/chmod 600 /opt/utab.yaml',
  require => S3file['/opt/utab.yaml']
}


if ( $::virtual == 'xenhvm' and defined(S3file['/opt/utab.yaml']) ) {
  $uhash=loadyaml('/opt/utab.yaml')
  create_resources(iop_users::usercreate, $uhash)
}

}
```

If I run this then here is some typical output.  The manifest fails as the initial "secret" used to find the path is not loaded

```
https_proxy=https://puppet:3128 puppet agent -t 
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Info: Caching catalog for ip-10-40-1-68.eu-west-1.compute.internal
Info: Applying configuration version '1431531382'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Iop_users/S3file[/opt/utab.yaml]/Exec[fetch /opt/utab.yaml]/returns:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Notice: /Stage[main]/Iop_users/S3file[/opt/utab.yaml]/Exec[fetch /opt/utab.yaml]/returns:                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
Notice: /Stage[main]/Iop_users/S3file[/opt/utab.yaml]/Exec[fetch /opt/utab.yaml]  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
Notice: /Stage[main]/Iop_users/S3file[/opt/utab.yaml]/Exec[fetch /opt/utab.yaml]/returns: curl: (56) Received HTTP code 404 from proxy after CONNECT
Error: curl -L -o /opt/utab.yaml https://s3-eu-west.amazonaws.com/mybucket//utab.yaml returned 56 instead of one of [0]
Error: /Stage[main]/Iop_users/S3file[/opt/utab.yaml]/Exec[fetch /opt/utab.yaml]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: curl -L -o /opt/utab.yaml https://s3-eu-west.amazonaws.com/mybucket//utab.yaml returned 56 instead of one of [0]
Notice: /Stage[main]/Iop_users/Exec[fix perms]: Dependency Exec[fetch /opt/utab.yaml] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Iop_users/Exec[fix perms]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: secretpath is 
Notice: /Stage[main]/Iop_users/Notify[show secretpath]/message: defined 'message' as 'secretpath is '
Notice: Finished catalog run in 1.28 seconds
```

However on the same host that the above puppet agent run fails on, if I use "apply" to try it outside of the context of a manifest, it works fine

```
puppet apply -e '$z=file("/etc/secret") notify { "z": message => $z}'
Notice: Compiled catalog for ip-x.x.x.x.eu-west-1.compute.internal in environment production in 0.02 seconds
Notice: wombat

Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Notify[z]/message: defined 'message' as 'wombat
'
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.03 seconds
```

What am I doing wrong?  Are there any better alternative approaches I could make?

Comment: Are you running both commands as the same user?

Comment: yes Chris, both as root.  The file is 644 at the moment so I if it is permissions it's not an obvious thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual I was confused about the way puppet works

Apparently, functions are always executed on the master

So any files being loaded in this way must be on the master

As soon as I added a "/etc/secret" file to the puppetmaster it all worked